# DataTrigger Not Triggering

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, inotifypropertychanged, datatrigger

I'm getting SO frustrated here.. I can't get these datatriggers to consistently work..

It works when I first run the program as I initialize a global UdpMessageAuthentication class (as it sets it to "test0"... but then I have a button that calls the SendAuthPacket method.. and from debugging I see it go into the OnPropertyChanged when I hit the button but the label won't change caption or color or any other property...once I use AuthenticateStatus to "test1".

Obviously I tried more realistic variables besides test0 and test1 but no matter what I'm doing I can't get the triggers to update

Please help =T

```
<Label Name="Label_Authentication" Margin="5,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="14">
<Label.Style>
    <Style TargetType="Label">
        <Setter Property="Content" Value="Initial Content"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value ="Red"></Setter>

        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=AuthenticateStatus}" Value="test0">
                <Setter Property="Content" Value="Authentication Required" />
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"></Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=AuthenticateStatus}" Value="test1">
                <Setter Property="Content" Value="Attempting Authentication..." />
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"></Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
            etc....


public class UdpMessageAuthentication : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _authenticateStatus;

    public string AuthenticateStatus
    {
        get { return _authenticateStatus; }
        set
        {
            if (_authenticateStatus != value)
            {
                _authenticateStatus = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Authenticate Status");
            }
        }
    }

    public UdpMessageAuthentication()
    {
        _udpClient = new UdpClient();
        AuthenticateStatus = "test0";
    }

    public void SendAuthPacket(IPAddress ip, string userID)
    {
        etc etc....
        AuthenticateStatus = "test1";
        etc etc....
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you explicitly set the [Mode Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.mode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) when you use (any) binding.

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=AuthenticateStatus, Mode=OneWay}" Value="test0">
```

Also, you have to make sure you're raising the property changed event with the PropertyName string set to exactly the name of the proprty being raised, since the system is using Reflection under the hood to find the changed property based on said string. Thus, try using this in your ViewModel:

```
get { return _authenticateStatus; }
set
{
    if (_authenticateStatus != value)
    {
        _authenticateStatus = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("AuthenticateStatus");
    }
}
```

Comment: wow.. i didn't know it was because i had a space in the AuthenticateStatus portion.. I always thought I could write whatever i wanted there.. tyvm!  i've been working on this all day and have been so frustrated.. will give you credit once the 5 minute timer goes away!

Comment: Glad I could help. Another trick for you down the road; because it uses this string to lookup the property, you can force WPF to grab data from any property, even if it doesn't have a Set defined, just by using the right ProprtyName. I use this to do some filtering and calculations on occasion, when Mutlibinding won't do the job.

Comment: can you give me an example of what you mean?  i think i get what you're saying but I would like to make sure i completely understand correctly so i can use this too in the future